# reading bytes without using any loop

Tags: java, android

I have a 16mb binary file and I want to read bytes without using any loop. like if i want to read 16 byte i can pass 16 to some method(if there is any) and it give me my desired result... right now i am using loop for reading bytes but my application is so huge i am afraid that it do not get slow.kindly give me some hint.

thanks alot.

Comment: What do you think happens in the magical method you pass the number in?

Comment: but my team lead was forcing me to search some thing i asked him in method there must a loop but he said no, it might be different.

Comment: Perhaps you could put a relevant code snippet in your question, and perhaps ask if it is performant, or if there are any improvements that can be made?

Comment: I think your team leader was thinking about buffered readers, but then again you'll need loops to read through them.

Comment: What do u mean by application getting slow. Are you going to loop in the main thread blocking everything else? It sure must be a different thread performing the read. Also, what do u do, by keeping a 16MB file in memory in an application running on device? 

On a side note, using loop with buffered readers is by far the most effective way of performing I/O.

Comment: I think the real problem here is that you and your team lead are not communicating effectively.

Comment: The only way to read w/o loop (in java or jni code but not kernel) is using a Direct Buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;

public class NoLoopReader {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName = args[0];
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    File file = new File(fileName);
    int size = (int)file.length();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer,0,size);
  }
}
```

Comment: That `is.read(byte[], int, int)` contains a for loop in the implementation.

Comment: wrapping into BufferedInputStream is a bad idea and helps nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you two answers, but they're not practical. In real life you'll use a loop to read the bytes.

**Valid answer 1**

```
public byte[] readWithNoLoop(InputStream in, int size) {
   byte[] result = new byte[16777216];  // 16 MByte
   byte b = 0;

   if ((b = in.read()) >= 0) result[0] = b;
   if ((b = in.read()) >= 0) result[1] = b;
   if ((b = in.read()) >= 0) result[2] = b;

   // ...

   if ((b = in.read()) >= 0) result[16777215] = b;

   return b;
}
```

**Valid answer 2**

use a massive parallel systems that can read the file in parallel. You need 16777216 processing units and a supporting file storage system but you can read in O(1) (theoretically).

---

If you encounter massive perfomance problems while reading the file, check if you use a BufferedInputStream, reading bytes from a 'normal' stream kills performance. ([Example](http://www.javadb.com/read-from-file-using-bufferedreader))

If it still doesn't help, then have a look at the `java.nio` classes. They can map files to memory. The [Grep example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/index.html) should give you a direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BufferedInputStream#read(byte[] b, int off, int len)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int))

Comment: Yes, but: 1) The implementation of that contains loops; 2) You need to loop in your client code to read from it safely.  I'm not saying it's a bad idea, I'm pointing out that the requirements are nonsensical and a better answer would be "WTF do you want to do that for" rather than trying to conform to them.

Comment: Yes, I thought requirements were about reading n bytes in a single call instead of inefficiently reading them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You might check file size on disk, create appropriate buffer and use this read method to do bulk load (as you can see it calls native readBytes). Of course I have no idea if there is no loop inside of readBytes (most likely there is, but that may depend on implementation of JVM)... :)

In FileInputStream

```
/**
 * Reads up to <code>b.length</code> bytes of data from this input
 * stream into an array of bytes. This method blocks until some input
 * is available.
 *
 * @param      b   the buffer into which the data is read.
 * @return     the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or
 *             <code>-1</code> if there is no more data because the end of
 *             the file has been reached.
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 */
public int read(byte b[]) throws IOException {
```

return readBytes(b, 0, b.length);
    }

```
/**
 * Reads up to <code>len</code> bytes of data from this input stream
 * into an array of bytes. If <code>len</code> is not zero, the method
 * blocks until some input is available; otherwise, no
 * bytes are read and <code>0</code> is returned.
 *
 * @param      b     the buffer into which the data is read.
 * @param      off   the start offset in the destination array <code>b</code>
 * @param      len   the maximum number of bytes read.
 * @return     the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or
 *             <code>-1</code> if there is no more data because the end of
 *             the file has been reached.
 * @exception  NullPointerException If <code>b</code> is <code>null</code>.
 * @exception  IndexOutOfBoundsException If <code>off</code> is negative, 
 * <code>len</code> is negative, or <code>len</code> is greater than 
 * <code>b.length - off</code>
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 */
public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
```

return readBytes(b, off, len);
    }